# Would it work to label 1/5th of my data and once I learn a classifier to slowly provide the unlabeled data?

Tags: python, classification, text-mining

I need to **classify MOOC video scripts into one of 5 classes which specify the intent of the sentence, e.g. `explanation`, `example`, `summary` etc., sentence-wise.**

I have 11 courses extracted and selected equal ratio of files from every course based on the number of files I have for each of them. Say course 1 has 100 files and course 2 has 5 times less, then I selected data for labeling such that the labeled daya for course 1 will be 5 times more than the labeled data for course 2.

Due to lack of time, **I wanted to label 1/5th of my data**, which is about ~8800 sentences in 111 files. **My question is.. can this be enough to predict the rest of the data**, or approx ~29600 sentences more.. maybe if i slowly introduce it to the model, not at once.. or i don't know.. any ideas are welcome, since I am not too experiences. Also **specific text classification algorithms** you think work best, **would be very helpful** to mention too. I am open to trying several, as long as their implementation is not too much time-consuming. I will of course try the most common ones first such as Naive Bayes and SVM.

Oh also, **another noob question** - do I need to convert my text into vectors for some reason? Or will the classifier do it's own work based on the textual data?

Comment: This question is too broad; you can learn the basics of text classification with this tutorial: https://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html